Is there a way to create vertical header for table in PrimeReact library?
I want the headers in my table to be displayed vertically along the left side of the table instead of the top.
I’ve looked through the PrimeReact documentation and haven’t found a clear solution for this. Maybe there something I didn't look up at.
For now, I see the only way how I can represent data using row section it is just to spare data throught column representation of table.
